# Any way to reduce diameter of hot glue sticks without doing it manually?

Tags: adhesive

I needed to reduce the diameter of some hot glue sticks I had lying around to about half their diameter for a project I was building. I need to shrink them down to a non-standard diameter (smaller than standard glue gun sizes).

Is there any possible way to do this without having to chop it in half manually? I was initially thinking of using some kind of rollers, but that made it brittle instead. Now I'm thinking of thrusting the glue sticks using motors in a funnel made of sheet metal, which is being heated. Is there any other way?

Comment: Buy the right size, it's easier.

Comment: buy new ones for $3 at wally world. Make life simple

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Is this so that the sticks can fit a thinner glue gun, or for some other purpose? (Edit your question to make it clear.)

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't make it clear enough, but I need to shrink them not to fit another glue gun, in fact, I need to shrink them down to a non-standard diameter (too small for any glue gun). Which is why I can't just "buy the right size".

Answer (score 1):

Melt them and pump them into a tube (preferably teflon, I'd guess, so you can remove it) of the new size.